# How can I reset the tezos-client alias?

Tags: tezos-client

When I was trying to set up a test net I used a docker installation and it's messed with the tezos-client.

I am now using mainnet again.

./tezos-client rpc get /chains/main/is_bootstrapped

is failing with this error:

```
Warning:
  
                 This is NOT the Tezos Mainnet.
  
           Do NOT use your fundraiser keys on this network.

Fatal error:
  Unexpected server answer
```

I can make it work with using -E http://localhost:8732

My question is how can I reset the tezos-client to use mainnet, not florencenet or granadanet?

I've already done

```
./tezos-node config reset
```

but to no avail.

Answer (score 0):

`tezos-client` has its own config. You can reset that in a similar way `tezos-client config reset` or just delete the file. By default it's stored at `~/.tezos-client/config`

Comment: Thanks! This worked.

Answer (score 0):

Your client is connecting to a node at localhost:8732 and the client is telling you that this node is not a mainnet node.

You were correct in resetting the node config file, but now you need to restart your node and resync the mainnet blockchain.

Best steps:

1. Stop node
2. Erase all node data (rm -rf ~/.tezos-node/*)
3. Download recent snapshot from https://mainnet.xtz-shots.io/
4. Import snapshot to node
5. Start node
6. Wait for sync (a few minutes)

Make sure you are on the latest Octez v9.7 before starting up.